# refactor and move controller code into model issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm running into some issues that I'm not aware of how to solve when I'm improving my code.

Currently in my controller#show I have this ugly piece of code:

```
def show
  @room = Room.find(params[:id])
  if user_signed_in?
    gon.push(
      session_id: @room.session_id,
      api_key: 453,
      token: current_user.tokens.last.token
    )
  elsif customer_signed_in?
    gon.push(
      session_id: @room.session_id,
      api_key: 453,
      token: current_customer.tokens.last.token,
      customer_id: current_customer.id
    )
  elsif @room.price == 0.0
    @token = OT.generate_token @room.session_id
    gon.push(
      session_id: @room.session_id,
      api_key: 453,
      token: @token
    )
  else
    @customer = Customer.new
  end
end
```

now I would like to move this into the rooms model. The issue that I'm having is that I'm having an if else based on if it's a user, customer or neither. How would I go about moving this into a model and still be able to validate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you would like to move this method to the model. (Are you using it from different places in your code? or just from this specific place?).

I would refactor this to the following:

```
def show
  @room = Room.find(params[:id])
  gon_args = { session_id: @room.session_id, api_key: 453, token: nil }
  if user_signed_in?
    gon_args.merge!(token: current_user.tokens.last.token)
  elsif customer_signed_in?
    gon_args.merge!(token: current_customer.tokens.last.token, customer_id: current_customer.id)
  elsif @room.price == 0.0
    gon_args.merge!(token: OT.generate_token(@room.session_id))
  else
    @customer = Customer.new
  end
  gon.push(gon_args) unless gon_args[:token].nil?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a [PORO (Plain Old Ruby Object)](http://www.bootyard.com/programming/poro-for-unique-business-logic.html). Not only does it keep stuff clean, it helps a *bunch* in testing your app and keeping single responsibilities across your code. I'm sure you can do much better than below but this is just a starting point.

```
class YourController
  def show
    @room = Room.find(params[:id])
    # no clue where some stuff comes from
    pusher = RoomPusher.new @room, @token, gon
    pusher.push
  end
end

class RoomPusher
  include YourHelpers
  def initialize(room, token, endpoint)
    @endpoint = endpoint
    @room = room
    @token = token
  end

  def push
    if user_signed_in?
      @endpoint.push(
        session_id: @room.session_id,
        api_key: 453,
        token: current_user.tokens.last.token
      )
    elsif customer_signed_in?
      @endpoint.push(
        session_id: @room.session_id,
        api_key: 453,
        token: current_customer.tokens.last.token,
        customer_id: current_customer.id
      )
    elsif @room.price == 0.0
      @token = OT.generate_token @room.session_id
      @endpoint.push(
        session_id: @room.session_id,
        api_key: 453,
        token: @token
      )
    else
      @customer = Customer.new
    end
  end
end
```